# Using existing values in l3keys

Tags: l3keys

How does the following print

```
Heime Borgia
405 Hilgard Ave
Los Angeles
California
90095
United States

Likku Cirillu
409 Hilgard Ave
```

rather than

```
Heime Borgia
405 Hilgard Ave
Los Angeles
California
90095
United States

Likku Cirillu
409 Hilgard Ave
Los Angeles
California
90095
United States
```

I want the second call to use the existing values
from the first call for the variables not set by the
second call.

The implementation is

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\keys_define:nn { adr_keys }
  {
    name .tl_set:N = \l_adr_name_tl,
    role .tl_set:N = \l_adr_role_tl,
    kmpn .tl_set:N = \l_adr_kmpn_tl,
    dwlg .tl_set:N = \l_adr_dwlg_tl,
    hmlt .tl_set:N = \l_adr_hmlt_tl,
    vltw .tl_set:N = \l_adr_vltw_tl,
    cbrg .tl_set:N = \l_adr_cbrg_tl,
    knty .tl_set:N = \l_adr_knty_tl,
    pstc .tl_set:N = \l_adr_pstc_tl,
    ktry .tl_set:N = \l_adr_ktry_tl,
  }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \adr_print:n
  {
    \keys_set:nn { adr_keys } { #1 }

    \begin {tabular} { @{} l@{} }

      \tl_use:N \l_adr_name_tl \\

      \tl_if_blank:VF \l_adr_role_tl
        { \tl_use:N \l_adr_role_tl \\ }

      \tl_if_blank:VF \l_adr_kmpn_tl
        { \tl_use:N \l_adr_kmpn_tl \\ }

      \tl_if_blank:VF \l_adr_dwlg_tl
        { \tl_use:N \l_adr_dwlg_tl \\ }

      \tl_if_blank:VF \l_adr_hmlt_tl
        { \tl_use:N \l_adr_hmlt_tl \\ }

      \tl_if_blank:VF \l_adr_vltw_tl
        { \tl_use:N \l_adr_vltw_tl \\ }

      \tl_if_blank:VF \l_adr_cbrg_tl
        { \tl_use:N \l_adr_cbrg_tl \\ }

      \tl_if_blank:VF \l_adr_knty_tl
        { \tl_use:N \l_adr_knty_tl \\ }

      \tl_if_blank:VF \l_adr_pstc_tl
        { \tl_use:N \l_adr_pstc_tl \\ }

      \tl_if_blank:VF \l_adr_ktry_tl
        { \tl_use:N \l_adr_ktry_tl \\ }

    \end {tabular}
  }

\NewDocumentCommand {\adrLflush} { m }
  {
    \begin {flushleft}
      \adr_print:n { #1 }
    \end {flushleft}
  }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\adrLflush
  {
    name={Heime Borgia},
    dwlg={405 Hilgard Ave},
    cbrg={Los Angeles},
    knty={California},
    pstc={90095},
    ktry={United States},
  }

\adrLflush
  {
    name={Likku Cirillu},
    dwlg={409 Hilgard Ave},
  }

\end{document}
```

Comment: you are making local assignments inside a `flushleft` environment. All environments restore all local assignments that is basic latex behaviour unrelated to any specifics of the code. use global (`gset`) assigments if you want to escape an environment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are making local assignments so they are restored at `\end{flushleft}` you seem to want global assignments.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\keys_define:nn { adr_keys }
  {
    name .tl_gset:N = \g_adr_name_tl,
    role .tl_gset:N = \g_adr_role_tl,
    kmpn .tl_gset:N = \g_adr_kmpn_tl,
    dwlg .tl_gset:N = \g_adr_dwlg_tl,
    hmlt .tl_gset:N = \g_adr_hmlt_tl,
    vltw .tl_gset:N = \g_adr_vltw_tl,
    cbrg .tl_gset:N = \g_adr_cbrg_tl,
    knty .tl_gset:N = \g_adr_knty_tl,
    pstc .tl_gset:N = \g_adr_pstc_tl,
    ktry .tl_gset:N = \g_adr_ktry_tl,
  }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \adr_print:n
  {
    \keys_set:nn { adr_keys } { #1 }

    \begin {tabular} { @{} l@{} }

      \tl_use:N \g_adr_name_tl \\

      \tl_if_blank:VF \g_adr_role_tl
        { \tl_use:N \g_adr_role_tl \\ }

      \tl_if_blank:VF \g_adr_kmpn_tl
        { \tl_use:N \g_adr_kmpn_tl \\ }

      \tl_if_blank:VF \g_adr_dwlg_tl
        { \tl_use:N \g_adr_dwlg_tl \\ }

      \tl_if_blank:VF \g_adr_hmlt_tl
        { \tl_use:N \g_adr_hmlt_tl \\ }

      \tl_if_blank:VF \g_adr_vltw_tl
        { \tl_use:N \g_adr_vltw_tl \\ }

      \tl_if_blank:VF \g_adr_cbrg_tl
        { \tl_use:N \g_adr_cbrg_tl \\ }

      \tl_if_blank:VF \g_adr_knty_tl
        { \tl_use:N \g_adr_knty_tl \\ }

      \tl_if_blank:VF \g_adr_pstc_tl
        { \tl_use:N \g_adr_pstc_tl \\ }

      \tl_if_blank:VF \g_adr_ktry_tl
        { \tl_use:N \g_adr_ktry_tl \\ }

    \end {tabular}
  }

\NewDocumentCommand {\adrLflush} { m }
  {
    \begin {flushleft}
      \adr_print:n { #1 }
    \end {flushleft}
  }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\adrLflush
  {
    name={Heime Borgia},
    dwlg={405 Hilgard Ave},
    cbrg={Los Angeles},
    knty={California},
    pstc={90095},
    ktry={United States},
  }

\adrLflush
  {
    name={Likku Cirillu},
    dwlg={409 Hilgard Ave},
  }

\end{document}
```

Comment: What would be a good strategy that allows both possibilities: global and local, with global as option.

Comment: a good strategy would be not to do that

Comment: the overwhelmingly common case would be just to use local, and here re-structure your calls so the key setting is before the flush environment not in it

Comment: Really. The functionality I am discussing is allowing existing values or resetting them when using `\adrLflush`.

Comment: So putting `\keys_set:nn { adr_keys } { #1 }` before the flush environment.

Comment: yes but you'd have to re-arrange a bit so you don't call it twice

Comment: Quite Right.  How would one handle using existing values and resetting them to empty ?  `ktry .initial:n = \l_adr_ktry_tl,` would keep initial values. right ?  What option would I have to add far refreshing the variables ?

Comment: we have already told you that 1000 times, just reset by `\keys_set:nn { adr_keys } { ktry=}`  or `\let \l_adr_ktry_tl\@empty` or however you like.

Comment: why do you keep asking about `initial` it does nothing about "resetting" anything, it is just equivalent to calling `\keys_set:nn ` once to set a value after the definition.

Comment: I would then need to use `default`.  My current difficulty is when to use `initial` and `default` and when not to bother about them.  Because I can always reset the variable values to empty.

Comment: no why would you have to use default???? just do as you have been told multiple times, you do not need to change the key declaration or use default or initial, neither of which are related to resetting the values, just set the keys again or directly defint the macros to empty as I showed in a comment above

Comment: Ok.  Have included a starred version. The unstarred version empties the variables, whereas the starred version uses existing values without emptying.

Comment: sounds reasonable @Ragonese